# activiti 7 candidate user to task

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

In the version 6 of activiti API I use this code to assign user as current logged and task:

```
identityService.setAuthenticatedUserId("ciro");
```

How can I do it inside API 7 version?

Answer (score -1):

```
Authentication.setAuthenticatedUserId(authenticatedUserId);
```

Comment: Try to give some more context and explain why/how your answer solves the problem exposed in the question.